# dconf/user all over the filesystem

Tags: dconf

(Sorry, I am aware that this question sounds rather stupid:) Somehow my system generates in all kind of places within my home directory tree directories called `dconf`, containing a single binary file `user` (files and directories are owned by me, btw). In total there are more than a hundred of these directories.

How can I get rid of these directories for good (something in creating and recreating them, in a manner and a rate I do not understand)?

I could not find anybody with the same problem via google. gconf related questions seem to concentrate on gnome and NFS, therefore maybe I should mention: Gnome is not used and not installed (apart from some things that seem to be installed by default, such as  gnome-settings-daemon), and my system doesn't run a regular X server (it runs two vnc4servers with xfwm4). I do not access the system via NSF.

Comment: can you give a few examples ?

Comment: sorry, not sure how to give an example other than:I have, e.g., a directory `~/work/papers/`. Somehow/somtimes there appeared a directory `~/work/papers/dconf` containing the file `user`, containing two null bytes and nothing else.

Comment: check out output of  `env` in terminal

Comment: sorry, don't know what to look for in the env output? nothing seems out of the ordinary there; I think I know what all the variables are doing and how they are set (apart from XDG_RUNTIME_DIR, XDG_SESSION_COOKIE and 
XDG_SESSION_ID)